# How to build a semantic bootstrap 4 sticky navbar on a WordPress website?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I need help with creating a more semantic code for a sticky bootstrap 4 navbar on a WordPress website. Every example I found online that works with my project relies on injecting a wrapper div above the navbar in order to maintain the top offset by resizing it on scroll, which I'll admit is a practical solution, but as far as I can tell it doesn't really make for a semantically correct use of html.

So my code at the moment looks like this:

```
<header class="header hidden-sm-down">
  <a href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>" id="logo">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/img/logo.svg" alt="logo">
  </a>
  <p class="tagline">
    <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>
  </p>
</header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light sticky" data-toggle="sticky-onscroll">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-group">
      <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up float-xs-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/img/hamburger-icon.svg" alt="hamburger">
        MENU
      </button>
      <a href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/img/logo-small.svg" alt="logo">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="exCollapsingNavbar">
      <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle">
      <label for="toggle">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/img/search-icon.svg" class="search-icon">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/img/close-icon.svg" class="close-icon">
      </label>
      <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main_menu', 'walker' => new bs4navwalker(), 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav clearfix' ) ); ?>
      <form action='<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>' method='get' class="search">
        <button class="btn" type="submit"><span><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/img/search-icon.svg"></span></button>
        <span><input type="text" name='s' id='s' placeholder="Search"></span> 
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<main class="container">
</main>
```

SCSS:

```
/** 4.0 - MENUS
================================================== **/

.navbar {
    @include border(border-top);
    @include border(border-bottom);
    border-radius: 0;
    min-height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    .container {
        position: relative;
    }
    .nav-group {
        @include clearfix;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 38px;
        float: left;
        padding: 0;
        @include media-breakpoint-up-md {
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            left: 15px;
            top: 0;
        }
        img {
            height: 10px;
            width: 138px;
        }
    }
    .navbar-toggler {
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 38px;
        padding: 0;
        @include font-size-base;
        line-height: 1;
        background: none;
        @include no-border;
        outline:none;
        width: auto !important;
        span {
            display: flex;
            align-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        img {
            margin-right: 2px;
            height: 14px;
            width: 14px;
        }
    }
    @include media-breakpoint-down-sm {
        .container {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        @include media-breakpoint-up-md {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .nav-item {
            @include media-breakpoint-up-md {
                display: inline-block;
                float: none;                
                margin: 0 15px;
            }   
            @include media-breakpoint-only-md {
                margin: 0 10px;
            }
            @include media-breakpoint-down-sm {
                float: none;
                display: block;
            }
            a {
                color: $gray-3;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                @include font-base;
                @include font-size-spacing ($fs-xxs, 2px);
                line-height: 38px;
                padding: 0;
                &:hover,
                &:active,
                &:focus {
                    color: $color-secondary;
                }
            }
        }
        .active>.nav-link {
            color: $color-secondary;
        }
    }
    .search {
        @include media-breakpoint-up-md {
            position: absolute;
            padding: 0 15px;
            width: 100%;            
            background: $white;
            top: -185px;
            left: 0;
            height: 92px;
            transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
            overflow: hidden;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        @include media-breakpoint-down-sm {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        button {
            background: $color-secondary;
            height: 40px;
            @include no-border;
            float: right;
            padding: 0;
            width: 40px;
            line-height: 26px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            @include media-breakpoint-up-md {
                display: none;
            }
            span {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }
            img {
                height: 16px;
                width: 16px;
            }
        }
        span {
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        input {
            border-radius: 0;
            @include border(border);
            background: $gray-2;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            padding-left: 15px;
            @include font-base;
            @include font-size-spacing ($fs-xxs, 2px);
            height: 40px;
            line-height: 26px;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 25px;
            @include media-breakpoint-down-sm {
                 margin-top: 10px;          
            }
        }
    }
    #toggle {
        position:absolute;
        appearance:none;
        cursor:pointer;
        left:-100%;
        top:-100%;
        @include media-breakpoint-down-sm {
            display: none;
        }
    }   
    #toggle + label {
        position:absolute;
        cursor:pointer;
        transition:all 500ms ease;          
        background: $color-secondary;
        height: 26px;
        @include no-border;
        right: 15px;
        top: 6px;
        padding: 0;
        width: 26px;
        line-height: 26px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: 5;
        @include media-breakpoint-down-sm {
            display: none;
        }
        img {
            height: 12px;
            width: 12px;
        }
        .close-icon {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    #toggle:checked ~ .search {
        top: -93px;
    }
    #toggle:checked + label .search-icon {
        display: none;
    }
    #toggle:checked + label .close-icon {
        display: block;
    }
}

.nav {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    @include font-size-spacing ($fs-xxs, 2px);
}

.sticky.is-sticky {
    background-color: $color-primary;
    border-color: $color-primary;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    @include admin-sticky-fix;
    .navbar-nav {
        .nav-link {
            &:hover {
                color: $color-secondary;
            }
        }
    }
    .nav-item {
        a {
            color: $white;
        }
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        @include media-breakpoint-up-md {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    }
    .navbar-toggler {
        svg {
            fill: $white;
        }
        span {
            color: $white;
        }
    }
    .search {
        @include media-breakpoint-up-md {       
            background: $color-primary;
            padding-right: 41px;
            left: 0;
            height: 40px;
            transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
            overflow: hidden;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            input{
                height: 26px;
                margin-top: 7px;
            }
        }
    }
    #toggle:checked ~ .search {
        top: -1px;
    }
}

@include media-breakpoint-down-sm {
    .navbar-toggleable-sm .navbar-nav {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}

#wpadminbar {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

And I'm also using this mixin for WordPress admin bar offset:

```
//admin sticky fix
@mixin admin-sticky-fix( $offset: 0 ) {
    $narrow-offset: 46px;
    $wide-offset: 32px;
    @if $offset != 0 and type-of($offset) == 'number' {
        $narrow-offset: $narrow-offset + $offset;
        $wide-offset: $wide-offset + $offset;
    }
    .admin-bar & {
        top: $narrow-offset;
        @media screen and (min-width: 783px) {
            top: $wide-offset;
        }
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
    /* STICKY NAVBAR
    ================================================== */ 
    var stickyToggle = function(sticky, stickyWrapper, scrollElement) {
        var stickyHeight = sticky.outerHeight();
        var stickyTop = stickyWrapper.offset().top;
        var adminBar = $('#wpadminbar').outerHeight(); 
        if (scrollElement.scrollTop() >= stickyTop - adminBar){
            stickyWrapper.height(40);
            sticky.addClass("is-sticky");
        } else{
            sticky.removeClass("is-sticky");
            stickyWrapper.height('auto');
        }
    };

    // Find all data-toggle="sticky-onscroll" elements
    $('[data-toggle="sticky-onscroll"]').each(function() {
        var sticky = $(this);
        var stickyWrapper = $('<div>').addClass('sticky-wrapper'); // insert hidden element to maintain actual top offset on page
        sticky.before(stickyWrapper);
        sticky.addClass('sticky');

        // Scroll & resize events
        $(window).on('scroll.sticky-onscroll resize.sticky-onscroll', function() {
            stickyToggle(sticky, stickyWrapper, $(this));
        });

        // On page load
        stickyToggle(sticky, stickyWrapper, $(window));
    });
```

This code works perfectly, but I would like to make it more semantic if it is possible. I'm not much of a jQuery and javascript expert, and I tried tinkering with it to no avail, so I was wondering is there a way to alter this jQuery code snippet so that it doesn't inject the wrapper div above navbar for top offset and that it instead perhaps adds a top margin to the main tag on scroll or something to that effect?
The main caveat to my code is that the header is hidden on small devices, so the navbar should be sticky out of the box on mobile, but this offsetting thing combined with the WordPress admin bar is giving me a great deal of trouble with making it actually behave the way i intended.

Comment: Well... an extra wrapper-div doesn't really do much for semantics when it comes to that mess, so I don't really see the point of stressing about it? divs are semantically neutral, so they don't really do much either way for semantics per se. What in the world is multiple inputs/labels and forms doing in a nav-menu anyway?

Comment: Form is a search form and checkbox/label are used to make the search form slide in and out from above when checked/unchecked.

Comment: Okay, I'll give you that, although most of is BS and not needed (apart from the slidetoggle for the search, perhaps) - here's a little cleaned up version of the HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/7rg5ze7y/ Almost no classes whatsoever, although that will probably break bootstrap - which is one of your main problems to start with, of course.

Comment: I need a .container div to center the .navbar content because I had to make the .navbar 100% width in order for it to have full width 1px top and bottom borders. I had to group .navbar-toggler and .navbar-brand inside the .nav-group div because the #exCollapsingNavbar was acting weird without it. It used to start listing items next to .navbar brand instead of bellow it and its width was smaller during the collapsing animation which looked really ugly.

Comment: I don't think you need what you think you need...